# Character Font Encoding C#

Tags: c#, vesa

So I'm working with VESA in C# and I'm trying to encode the font.

I know that you have to use an array of 1s and 0s and convert them into hexadecimal but I'm not quite sure how to create the arrays, and then declare the pixels used, could anyone help?

Comment: Description of the VESA tag: "VESA is intended for questions related to programmatic access to video card BIOS settings." This seems like quite an advanced topic for a developer asking about the basics of byte arrays.

Comment: Well, I'm just focusing more on the font encoding, and I'm not quite sure how to do that, and I was wondering if anyone could help me with the arrays @spender

Comment: @NathanSinger you can use font image like [Convert floating-point numbers to decimal digits in GLSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44797902/2521214) but if you are on VGA/VESA environment you can use its BIOS to obtain internal fonts then just copy it to your arrays and use at will...